# Pantheon greeter disappears when I mistype my password

Tags: greeter

No chance for a second try? 
I've read (now) that a delay is default for security reasons. Does this include removing the greeter completely, leaving a black screen? Is this the intended behavior when wrong passwords are typed?
Because from [the answers to this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/595/why-is-there-a-delay-when-i-enter-my-password-incorrectly) I (maybe mistankenly) had the impression  that the greeter remains there, but will not take inputs for the duration of the set delay.

Comment: this is a bug - no designed system would prevent from a *second* trial

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciated it. Any idea about how can I fix it?

Comment: Bugs should be reported on [github/greeter](https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues), but first let's try a few ideas. What exactly you mean by going black - does the screen switch off or it's on and shows nothing e.g. even after moving mouse? What happens if you try activating terminal (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1)? Can you login from there?

Comment: FYI if you wanna go back to graphical session from terminal session, press Ctrl+Alt+F7 ;)

Comment: I installed eOS not long ago (end of October or beginning of November, I think) and this was the first time I mistyped my password. When I did, the greeter disappeared, and the new greeter's black background was the only thing in the screen. I could see the mouse pointer moving, but nothing else, so I restarted the computer and made sure I typed the password very carefully, so I got in. I didn't know about the Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F7 options. Thanks for the tip. :) Next time I log in I will try it.